# QuillJS add custom blots for freemarker variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, freemarker, quill, parchment

So I have integrated the editor just fine and would like to use it as an online templating editor.

On the backend we use freemarker to process the template and therefor I need to be able to have freemarker tags supported in quill.

My example case is the <#list> tag. I have a custom button which switches the editor into an HTML-only view to edit markup, and then switch back to quill once the template stuff is in. Now it seems though as if quill always escaped the tag and wraps it in a paragraph (p-tag).

I tried adding a custom blot like this:

```
class FMListBlot extends InlineBlot {}
FMListBlot.blotName = "fmlist";
FMListBlot.tagName = "#list";
FMListBlot.scope = Scope.INLINE;
Quill.register(FMListBlot);
```

This however doesnt seem to work. The tag is not recognized and the hashtag always gets escaped. It would be fine if quill just doesnt show these custom tags, but the conversion always sanitizes it and doesnt allow my custom tag.

Any help?